# Não consigo colocar página no ar pelo github

Tags: git, github

Estou usando o git-bash, no final quando dou o comando `git push origin master`, aparece uma mensagem dizendo:

> "remote: Permission to aulasdelivery/aulasdelivery.github.io.git denied to guilhermepassos.
>
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/aulasdelivery/aulasdelivery.github.io.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
>   "

O que fazer?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, sou. acho que esse erro está aparecendo, pois já coloquei uma página no ar por outra conta do git, usando o mesmo pc

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, soube que para por páginas no ar pelo git, era necessario ter o repositorio com o mesmo nome que o usuario, entao criei duas contas no git: uma que eu consegui perfeitamente por no ar e a segunda que é a que etou tendo problemas

Comment: Mas as duas contas são adm do repositório mesmo, será que você não esta fazendo confusão?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pode ser que eu esteja fazendo confusao mesmo... Mas é realmente necessario que a o nome do repositorio seja o mesmo que o usuario para a pagina ir ao ar, não é?

Comment: não é bem isso, acho que você não esta entendendo bem o proposito e funcionamento do GIT, amigo. Independente do uso do GIT se é para paginas github ou outro lugar, você pode adicionar quem quiser como administrador, a questão é quem tem permissão e quem pode mandar pull-request e quem só pode fazer forks. Acho que talvez vc não tenha entendido bem o git :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ahh sim, entendi! Foi isso mesmo, consegui resolver meu problema. Obrigado!

Comment: Por nada, até breve